# Pandas to excel file corruption

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am converting a multi indexed dataframe to excel using df.to_excel. However when I am trying to open the excel file I am getting error starting, 'we are sorry we can't open your workbook. It's possibily corrupt or using a file format that's not supported '

Please help

I hav tried passing encoding= utf8 and also tried to change the engine still the issue is persisting

Comment: Have you tried engine='xlsxwriter'?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install openpyxl before you output the excel

```
pip install openpyxl
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014], [1, 2]],
                                   names=['year', 'visit'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Bob', 'Guido', 'Sue'], ['HR', 'Temp']],
                                     names=['subject', 'type'])

# mock some data
data = np.round(np.random.randn(4, 6), 1)
data[:, ::2] *= 10
data += 37

# create the DataFrame
health_data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

health_data.to_excel("./test.xlsx")
```

this work for me